# Ubuntu 22.04 fails to install on Acer laptop

Tags: 22.04, acer

I ran into a problem installing the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire-VN7-791G laptop.
At the beginning I am getting the
`Do you want to resume partitioning?` warning message as following:

```
You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu."
```

Here I click "Continue" and then the installation starts but this is what I get:

```
Install" window shows "Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #2 of SCSI6(0,0,0) (sda) ..." for many, many hours without completion the install.
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try this one, maybe it will help you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/502307/the-attempt-to-mount-a-file-system-with-type-vfat-in-ssi10-0-0-partition1sda

Comment: Thank you very much! That link helped.